# SQL vs. Entity Framework for databases at run-time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, ado.net

I'm currently building a query builder in C#, which first starts by prompting the user to specify which database they would like to query on their local machine.

Thus, the program allows databases to be "plugged-in" to it, rather than have a number of databases with tables that are always used.

Thus, for my query builder to generate SQL statements, would it make more sense to output and execute SQL statements in the form of strings, or could I use Entity Framework?  I have no experience with Entity Framework, however from what I can understand, it makes more sense to utilise EF if you've got a static database whose tables and schema you are aware of - versus potentially any database being specified by the user at run-time.

I've currently been working with SQL statements - i.e. the users' interaction with the query builder, literally executes string-based SQL statements which are generated by the application.  Would it be possible or worthwhile to switch to Entity Framework?

Comment: My opinion is that EF's benfits are arguable at best in static operational databases. Trying to use EF on a dynamic set of databases would be the stuff of my nightmares.

Comment: @gbtimmon - Thanks for the contribution - that's what I'm wondering :) The only reason I started considering switching to EF is because someone called my program "primitive" because it generates SQL statements rather than uses EF.

Comment: @DotNET - don't let others' techno-bigotry influence your architecture, especially one that you admittedly don't know much about.  Do research and/or a proof-of-concept then decide on your own what's best for your situation.

Comment: @gbtimmon Nightmare! That's the word! =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience using EF, if you are generating queries dynamically, you're better stick to SQL strings.

The only way you could use EF to query a unknown schema is by generating the Entities through reflection, which would be a hell of lot of work. And I'm not sure it would work. And also, you'd lose all benefits from using EF.

So, if this is the case, no.

Comment: I would only switch to EF if it makes things neater, and generally makes more sense all-round. If not, I'll leave it the way it is :)

Comment: If you're good with SQL, I'm not sure you should ever consider EF. I've used EF for many years, and now I'm almost back to manual SQL. Only context and object state management features are holding me. EF is too invasive, and very hard to test...

Comment: @LMB - can you provide more details. Have you used POCO and CodeFirst? Any specific improvements you have in mind? True that mocking EF and/or write real unit tests for DAL when using EF is hard (or sometimes impossible).

Comment: @Pawel Well, I could write an article on this... EF is very good for bringing an small app to run in one day time. But if you're on a serious project, you cant: 1-Use lazy querying; 2-Let lazy nav-properties into you BL; 3-Let IQueryable into your BL; 4-Access nav-properties that aren't loaded in the BL. Being more design strict, Entities are DB types, so, should never be known in BL, or worse, UI. I've used POCO most of the time and CodeFirst for a while. The better strategy, IMO, is designing the DB in a DBMS and then import the schema to EF. Then implement BL interfaces. In very few words!

Comment: @Pawel Ladislav Mrnka has written a lot about EF design problems in SO.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework does not provide any advantages in this scenario.  In fact, it limits severely.

It is possible to write a generic SortHelper, PagerHelper, FilterHelper, etc. that takes an expression tree as IQuerable and applies the sort you desire.  This sort of generic programming is great, as it avoids SQL Injection.

However, if you use Entity Framework for your query generator, you would have to use reflection to generate your Entity Data Model.  Moreover, you would have to decide how to do open-ended select statements.  Further, you would be tied to how Entity Framework represents and evaluates queries, which is still not as robust as it should be for an ORM at version 5.0!  For example, there is no good way to represent right joins, and you have to always represent them as left joins if you want decent SQL generated.  Another limitation is that if you want to write a projection, you would need to generate an anonymous class.  .NET does not have a good way to unload types from memory, and every type you generate in an AppDomain is held in memory until the AppDomain gets unloaded.  That is why F# 3.0 uses type erasure for its F# Type Providers API, to avoid generating a billion types for databases like RDF, where there are billions of "types".

Also, Entity Framework does not do any kind of serious analysis to decide if an expression can be transformed, like SAT solving.

I am basing my answer on real life experience, having built the exact application you are describing, and then some.  The application allowed business analysts to write queries visually and compose queries together.

That said, I do recommend studying Entity Framework's design vocabulary.  I have shifted over to using very similar vocabulary, even though I don't use Entity Framework.  For example, Navigational Properties.  I don't call them Properties, since that is an object-oriented abstraction for those who use object query languages and doesn't make sense in a visual query language.  I call them Paths.  But I like the Any() operator to imply left join, as well as Include().  Those little modeling ideas were valuable to me.